# Is there a desktop equivalent of the Android RefreshListView(and other android material design classes)

Tags: javafx

I am currently making a desktop application with JavaFX 8, and thought that a refresh animation like the one In the android framework would be well suited for getting the feed. However, in my (albeit limited) searches, I was unable to find a desktop equivalent. Does anyone have knowledge of the equivalent desktop library?

Comment: Please provide some code. What you have tried?

Comment: you mean a pull to refresh ? can you provide example